# Returning a promise from the Unirest client

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, unirest

Hi I'm trying to get Unirest to return a promise so that I can create a function, call it from an external process and return the response to the calling process. However, I can't work out how to get the promise to return the response.

This is what I have so far:

```
const unirest = require('unirest');

function auth() {
    yield unirest.post('https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/authorize/')
        .headers({'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
        .send({"Username": "user1", "Password": "password"})
        .end().exec();
}
auth()
```

However this throws the following error:

```
yield unirest.post('https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/authorize/')
      ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:528:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:590:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

Comment: why yield instead of return? that doesn't look like a generator,

Comment: I was following the suggestion made here: https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-nodejs/pull/60

Comment: that issue is still open, are you sure unirest even returns a promise at this point? that change doesn't appear to have been applied yet.

Comment: Hmm. OK maybe it doesn't and I've misread the issue. I guess I would need to look at an alternative in this case then.

Answer (score 1):

You don't make a promise return something, but you can return the promise from your function that will fulfill with the result. Since `.exec()` gives you the promise already, you can just `return` it:

```
function auth() {
    return unirest.post('https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/authorize/')
        .headers({'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
        .send({"Username": "user1", "Password": "password"})
        .end().exec();
}
auth().then(console.log);
```

I'm not sure why you wanted to `yield` anything. Promises should be consumed using [async functions](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait) (proposal for ES8), in which you can use `await` and which will always return a promise for the asynchronous result implictly:

```
async function auth() {
    const val = await unirest.post('https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/authorize/')
        .headers({'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
        .send({"Username": "user1", "Password": "password"})
        .end().exec();
    return val;
}
auth().then(console.log);
```

However that's unnecessary in your case, as you don't do anything with the value, so you can just return the promise straigt away.

> it throws the following error `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

You were trying to use the `yield` operator in a function that was not marked as a generator function. It's possible to use generators that use promises as a polyfill for async/await, by using a dedicated runner library such as `co`. Your code would look like this with it:

```
function* auth() {
//      ^
    const val = yield unirest.post('https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/authorize/')
        .headers({'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
        .send({"Username": "user1", "Password": "password"})
        .end().exec();
    return val;
}
co(auth()).then(console.log);
```